# How to reduce compiled binary size of type erasure

Tags: c++, destructor, type-erasure

I am developing firmware in C++.  As part of the firmware, I wrote my own, lightweight version of std::shared_ptr (without weak pointers and some other features) and std::make_shared.  Without weak pointers, the control block is destroyed at the same time as the object itself, so I was able to do the following:

```
template <typename T, typename ... ARGS>
shared_ptr<T> make_shared(ARGS&&... args) {
    struct FullBlock {
        _shared_ptr_base::control_block block;
        T value;
    };

    //Allocate block on heap
    auto block = new FullBlock{
        {0, {nullptr, nullptr}},
        T{std::forward<ARGS>(args)...} //value
    };

    block->block.destructor.p = block;
    block->block.destructor.destroy = [](const void* x){
        delete static_cast<const FullBlock*>(x);
    };

    return shared_ptr<T>(&block->block, &block->value);
}
```

Where `block.destructor.p` is a void* (type erased) pointer to the control block + object (i.e., FullBlock) and `block.destructor.destroy` is a function pointer to, in this case, a lambda that does the deleting.

I use these shared pointers primarily as part of a message-passing framework.  Since there are a lot of different types of messages, there are a lot of different instances of `make_shared` and thus the deleter lambda.  Each one of these lambdas requires space in `.text`.

My question is, since the destructors are just functions which take a (hidden) pointer to an object, is there a way to store the destructor without having to create a special lambda function for every single type that I pass to `make_shared`?

In my head, it should be as simple as the following (but I know it's not):

```
struct Foo;

using Destructor = void(*)(const void*);

Foo* f;
Destructor d = &Foo::~Foo;
void* ptr = static_cast<void*>(f);

d(ptr); //Call the destructor
```

Comment: Why bother? I'm willing to bet that if you just used the standard facilities and enabled your compilers optimizer (`-O2` or `-O3` for gcc and clang) and also enable LTO (Link Time Optimization), then the result would be the same or better than your hand rolled solution. Don't think you can outsmart the compiler.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Good point.  Mainly, I am hoping that I can make a hand-rolled solution that allows for easier debugging (which goes away when you use the higher levels of optimizations).

Comment: If you aren't going to support weak pointers you might consider going the intrinsic ref counter way, which is IMO even easier to debug

Comment: @UnholySheep Could you provide an example?

Comment: @PatrickWright just replace control block with (atomic?) int and call delete directly